# Input Field Not Updating after calling .replace()

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, regular-expressions

I have an input field on an LWC that should only accept numbers in the range [0-9]. I have a regex and a replace method. But the invalid characters only get removed after I enter a valid one. I could type aaaaaaa and the field will not update until I enter a number. Then the invalid characters get removed.

Is this something wrong with my understanding of data binding in this case? I would expect that the values specified for .replace() would be removed immediately.

HTML

```
template>
    <div class="container">      
      <lightning-input label="phone"
                        value={phone}
                        type="text"
                         onkeydown= {handleKeyPress}
      >
      </lightning-input>
    </div>
</template>
```

JS File

```
import { LightningElement} from "lwc";

export default class FormDemo extends LightningElement {

  phone;


  handleKeyPress(event) {
    const regex = /[^0-9]/g;
    let numbers2 = event.target.value;
    this.phone = numbers2.replace(regex, '')
    console.log(this.phone);
  }
}
```

This is the method based on SFDC Foxes guidance.

```
 preventDefault(event){
        const regex = /[^0-9()-\s]/g
        if (regex.test(event.key)) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
```

Comment: any reason you're using `type="text"` versus `type="tel"`?

Comment: Just a typo. This is a stripped-down version of the real code. I made for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it may have something to do with debouncing and/or the fact that an all non-numeric string ends up being empty after such a replacement (though I'm not entirely sure why this should happen).

It's usually better to ask for permission than to ask for forgiveness, so a better solution is to prevent any keys you don't want from getting through:

```
  handleKeyPress(event) {
    if(event.key < '0' || event.key > '9') {
      event.preventDefault()
    }
  }
```

Which you can handle as an actual keyPress (as opposed to keyDown or keyUp):

```
<lightning-input label="phone" value={phone} type="text" onkeypress={handleKeyPress}>
</lightning-input>
```

[Demo](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/3G0oMPT5O19WKSYiee8b/src/app.html?p=stories).

Note that this only stops casual typing, not things like copy-pasting or drag-copy, etc, so you'll want to pair this up with an onblur event to validate the input afterwards. You can also use the `pattern` attribute to require the input to match a desired pattern (e.g. `[0-9]*`) if you want to show an error.

Comment: That worked like a charm. I never would have thought of event.preventDefault(). I guess it is not just for submit buttons... :)

Comment: @BrooksJohnson Indeed, you can prevent almost all default browser behavior, aside from closing windows or leaving a site, including navigation, drag and drop, scroll events, and more.

Comment: @BrooksJohnson Side note, I think I figured it out; you're trying to change the key before the key is changed in the input field, so the rendering system is kind of in a race condition (as I speculated above). Doing "keyUp" might have been more reliable, but I'd still recommend just doing it during the keypress event as done here.

Comment: It works great. I will add the final implementation to the original post.